# Why php trim the digit before '@'

Tags: php

I tried to use php rtrim() function to retrive username in the email address, but I met the following problem:

Case 1:

```
$email = 'merkerxu37@stackoverflow.com';
echo rtrim($email, '@stackoverflow.com');
```

I got the output:

```
merkerxu37
```

Case 2:

```
$email = 'merkerxu37@37signals.com';
echo rtrim($email, '@37signals.com');
```

I got the output:

```
merkerxu
```

Can anybody tell me why the "37" is missing in Case 2?

Comment: rtrim doesn't remove the string you set; it treats it as a set of characters that should be removed

Comment: Read the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php the second parameter specifies a charset to remove.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the answer is readily available in the [manual](http://php.net/rtrim) .

Comment: Little hint: `strrev(substr(strpbrk(strrev($email), "@"), 1))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you have entered the second parameter `'@37signals.com'` which consider `3`, `7` or `37` as characters to be trimmed.

[Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php)

Answer (score 1):

`trim` (and its single-sided variants) take a list of characters to remove. Since `3` and `7` feature in the list you gave, it trimmed them.

Why not just do this?

```
echo explode("@",$email,2)[0];
// If you don't have PHP 5.4:
// $parts = explode("@",$email,2); echo $parts[0];
```

Comment: +1 - i was about to answer this :P

Comment: Keep in mind this will fail for emails such as `"Foo\@bar"@iana.org`. Which is a perfectly valid email.

Comment: @BenFortune Yes, but who uses email addresses like that? Chances are, nobody.

Comment: herpaderp logic: the probability is low, so we ignore it completely.